# Why do all my webpages have .html at the end and none of the professional webpages have this?

Tags: html, clean-urls

Why do all my webpages have `.html` at the end and none of the professional webpages have this?

Comment: what do you mean by professional webpages ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_URL

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/952645/2499019) answer. Good question.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730092/how-to-remove-html-from-url).

Comment: **Define "professional".**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `.html` because you saved them with that extension. Other sites may have used various technologies to dynamically generate webpages. Some of these may require different extension or none at all.

Answer (score 1):

URL rewriting can be one of the best and quickest ways to change that.

Assuming your site is hosted on an Apache server, you can rewrite the URL.

To see how to do that, refer [Apache URL Rewriting Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html)